# Show a Dialog() or MessageDialog() from the MainWindow.cs?

Tags: mono, gtk#

I'm trying to display a Dialog() or MessageDialog() from my MainWindow.cs (standard MainWindow.cs file that is created from the C# GTK# 2.0 Project template).

I'm getting a rather nasty error when using the below code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Gtk.Window
{   

    public MainWindow () : base(Gtk.WindowType.Toplevel)
    {
        Build();
    }

    public void CreateAlert(string message) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("CreateAlert() - message: {0}", message));
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog("Error", this, Gtk.DialogFlags.DestroyWithParent);
        dialog.Modal = true;
        dialog.AddButton ("OK", ResponseType.Close);
        dialog.Response += on_dialog_response;
        dialog.Run ();
        dialog.Destroy ();

    }
}
```

I believe the cause of this error is the second param in the Dialog() constructor - "this". My question is... how does one satisfy the second param of "Window win" when inside the MainWindow.cs?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You didn't post complete runnable code, and you have also forgotten to tell what the "nasty error" was. As it is, I have taken the time to make a complete test app and that works just fine.

Comment: When do you call CreateAlert? Maybe before entering the main loop?